# zip(,) string to float?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I am trying to compute a daily P&L, with 10 min prices in a .csv (there are 42 times for each date)---where number of buys and number of sells in a day could be unequal. If they are unequal, the program should use the closing price for that unique date df["price"][t] to subtract (from/by) depending on whether it's a buy or sell.

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv("file.csv", names="date time price mag signal".split())

s=df["signal"]=="S"
b=df["signal"]=="B"
ns=df["signal"]!="S"
nb=df["signal"]!="B"
t=df["time"]=="1620"

a1=df["price"][buy|(nb & t)]
b1=df["date"][buy|(nb & t)]

h=df["price"][s|(ns & t)]
g=df["date"][s|(ns & t)]


c1=zip(b1,a1)
c=zip(g,h)
```

c1, c are lists containing number of buys and sells, alongside its respective date. The problem here is c1 & c are strings--once they're zipped; hence cannot be subtracted. Is it possible to make a1, h floating point numbers so that I can difference them?

I want to match dates in c, c1 to subtract the prices at the Sells-Buys: S_i-B_i, for all i on a given day, then sum all and return that one value, for every date. I'd like to difference the prices at h-a1, only when the dates match.

Some sample data:

date    time    price   mag signal

1/3/2007    930 1422.8
1/3/2007    940 1423.2  0
1/3/2007    950 1422.8  0
1/3/2007    1000    1420.5  0
1/3/2007    1010    1422.8  0
1/3/2007    1020    1426.2  1  S

.
.
.

1/3/2007    1230    1424.2  -1  B

1/3/2007    1240    1424.8  0
1/3/2007    1250    1425.8  1   S

1/3/2007    1300    1426    0
1/3/2007    1310    1425    0
1/3/2007    1320    1423.5  -1  B

1/3/2007    1330    1421.8  0
1/3/2007    1340    1421.5  0
1/3/2007    1350    1420.5  0
1/3/2007    1400    1421    0
1/3/2007    1410    1417.2  -1  B

1/3/2007    1420    1412.8  -1  B

1/3/2007    1430    1414.8  0
1/3/2007    1440    1413.5  0
1/3/2007    1450    1410    0
1/3/2007    1500    1407.2  -1  B

1/3/2007    1510    1410.2  1   S

1/3/2007    1520    1409.5  -1  B

1/3/2007    1530    1410.5  1   S

1/3/2007    1540    1412.5  0
...

1/3/2007    1610    1415.5  1   S

1/3/2007    1620    1414    -1  B

1/4/2007    930 1412.2  0
1/4/2007    940 1411    0
1/4/2007    950 1413    0
1/4/2007    1000    1412.2  0
1/4/2007    1010    1407.2  -1  B

The result of the zip, say, c1 should look something like this:

```
[('1/3/2007', '1424.2'),
('1/3/2007', '1423.5'),
('1/3/2007', '1417.2'),
('1/3/2007', '1412.8'),
('1/3/2007', '1407.2'),
('1/3/2007', '1409.5'),
('1/3/2007', '1414'),

 etc - all dates in between

 ('8/30/2012','1324')]
```

Thanks very much.

Comment: `map` before (or even after) the `zip`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the zip, you can keep the data in pandas native datastructures.
Here prices should have read correctly as floats in the DataFrame.

You can do something like [`sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.sub.html) then [groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html) `'date'`:

```
df['dif'] = a1.sub(h, fill_value=0)
g = df.groubpy('date')['dif'].sum()
```

.

Note you can use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html) keyword `parse_dates` as datetime objects:

```
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv",
                 names="date time price mag signal".split()
                 parse_dates=[['date','time']])
```

Comment: After running this, the traceback gives:
 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str' which refers to sub() I'm not sure why? Since a1,h; prices, should both be floating point numbers.

Comment: @user1374969 are they all floating numbers? read_csv should pick floats correctly, but perhaps you could force it: `df['price'] = df['price'].apply(float)`

Comment: I ran a formula on the price col of the csv file. Indeed, they are all "numbers". apply(float) for some reason was rejected w/ValueError: could not convert string to float: price. 

The Traceback points to: -> mapped = lib.map_infer(self.values, f, convert=convert_dtype) as a problem here. Seems strange.

Comment: If you use the interactive debugger (pdb) you can find what value it was which give you the error (which may explain it).